# Which is correct? Tours & Travels or Tour & Travel

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have seen travel agencies use 'tours & travels' after their name. I also often see 'tour & travel'. What is the difference? Is that just the singular and plural difference?

Comment: Usually, we do not use the word travels in the modern, contemporary vocabulary in the tourist industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of agency names, it's all the same. I think that **tour and travel** refers more generically to the industry, while **tours and travels** refers more specifically to tours and travels. It's a very subtle difference.

Comment: Tour*s* and Travel. The one being typically used in a countable form and the other not.

Answer (score 0):

"Tour and Travel" or "Tours and Travel" would both be correct for a travel agency.

The word "travels" as a countable plural, however, mostly refers to someone's past experience of travelling, or trips a specific person is going to take, rather than the general concept of travel, so it's inappropriate for the name of a travel agency.